# What have they used to write their API documentation?

Tags: documentation, github-pages, code-documentation, gitbook

I was wondering what application/service have those guys used to write their documentation? I'm especially interested in that playground section in the right side.

https://docs.nftport.xyz/docs/nftport/b3A6MjE0MDYzNzY-upload-a-file-to-ipfs
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general framework is based on [Stoplight](https://meta.stoplight.io/).

The playground does seems to be done with various  section, associated to a form from:

```html
<pre tabindex="0" aria-label="curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/files \
  --header 'Authorization: ' \
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001' \
  --form file=" style="--fs-code: 12;" class="sl-code-viewer sl-overflow-x-hidden sl-overflow-y-hidden sl-relative sl-outline-none sl-group" role="group">
    <div style="max-height: 400px;" class="sl-code-viewer__scroller sl-overflow-x-auto sl-overflow-y-auto">
       <div style="padding: 12px 15px; font-family: var(--font-code); font-size: var(--fs-code); line-height: var(--lh-code);" class="sl-code-highlight prism-code language-bash">
...
```

Comment: cheers mate, that's it! 
btw quite pricy 1k/y